# Behavioural economics experiment - non parametric test

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, software, manova

I wonder if somebody could help with my dissertation project. I am stuck with the analysis and tried to consult a few people but unfortunately they either have limited experience, knowledge or interest in the subject of statistics/behavioural economics.

Basically, I got a mixed repeated measures design with 2 dependent variable (DV) and 2 independent variable (IV) (1 at 2 and 1 at 4 levels). There were 24 participants split between two groups. Each participant performed a task which was measured using two DV between groups. Also, in each group there were four levels of additional IV.

Given that I must use non-parametric tests (non-normal distribution) and i have 2 DV (and so MANOVA)  I do not think I could use the SPSS for this. I am not sure which tests to use and what software (R?).

Answer (score 3):

R would require a hefty amount of time for someone to learn the basics on the way to being able to conduct a multivariate procedure.  If your assessment is correct that you need to avoid parametric procedures, then MANOVA is out.  (But I suspect what you need are normal distributions of the DV *within each level of each IV*.  So it's worth checking into that again.)

For the community to give you more useful advice, you'll probably need to say more about the distributions of your DVs.  Also, in what way is the advice you're seeking specific to behavioural economics?  Finally, have you considered your level of statistical power? It would be a shame to put in the kind of work that a dissertation requires only to learn that you really would have needed many more subjects in order to have a decent chance of obtaining support for your hypothesis.